# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to solve two simultaneous nonlinear equations using the [`scipy.optimize.brute`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute) function

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so

def root2d(x,a,b):
   F1 = np.exp(-np.exp(-(x[0]+x[1]))) - x[1]*(b+x[0]**2)
   F2 = x[0]*np.cos(x[1]) + x[1]*np.sin(x[0]) - a
   return (F1,F2)

a = 0.5
b = 1

x0 = np.array([-0.1,0.1]) # initial guesses

rranges = (slice(-4,4,0.2),slice(-4,4,0.2))
print(so.brute(root2d,rranges,args=(a,b),finish=so.fmin))
```

I get an error that I don't understand: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ravel'`. What does this mean and how do I fix my code (if it's possible)?

**Edit:** full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-29b9507fcb99>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('.../test')

  File "C:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "../test.py", line 111, in <module>
    print(so.brute(root2d,rranges,args=(a,b),finish=so.fmin))

  File "C:\WinPython\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2711, in brute
    indx = argmin(Jout.ravel(), axis=-1)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

Comment: Show the full backtrace. The Python interpreter is giving you as much information as it can to help you solve the problem -- why wouldn't you include it here for others?

Comment: Since you are returning 2 variables so you need to access them as we do in list index fashion..

Comment: The function to minimize can only have one output. You will need to combine F1 and F2 or optimize them separately.

Comment: @-kazemakase How should I combine them? If it's like `F1*F2` or `F1+F2` the optimized values don't agree with results from `scipy.optimize.root`. No I can't optimize `F1` and `F2` separately as these are **simultaneous** nonlinear equations

Answer (score 2):

You return 2 variables F1 and F2 and reveive them using a single variable obj.(say) This is what is called a tuple obj,it  is associated with 2 values, the values of F1 and F2. So, use index as you use in a list to get the value you want, in order.